# ulong.Parse(string, NumberStyles) Exception C#

Tags: c#, parsing, formatexception

i been working on this "string to Binary" method for longer than usual and i have no idea where i m going wrong.

i have already searched the internet for solution but nothing seem to be working the way it supposed to do.

```
public static string hexToBin(string strValue)
    {
        byte[] hexThis = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strValue.ToString());

        string thiI = ToHex(strValue);
        ulong number = UInt64.Parse(*string*, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(number);

        string binaryString = string.Empty;
        foreach (byte singleByte in bytes)
        {
            binaryString += Convert.ToString(singleByte, 2);
        }

        return binaryString;
    }
```

ToHex(string) takes string and returns its hex representation.

but all i keep getting is "Input string was not in a correct format." at the ulong.Parse(string, NumberStyle); and no matter what are my inputs i keep getting the "FormatException" "Input string was not in a correct format." Error.

the inputs and its outputs

1. string: format exception - *"Hello"*
2. hex: format exception - *"48 65 6C 6C 6F"*
3. byte[]: format exception - *{ 72, 101, 108, 108, 111 }*
4. i have also tried using the "Hello" string, but it threw me the same error.

would you please let me know what i m doing wrong in here?
i also have tried "Clean/build/rebuild" restart visual studio, but i keep getting the same format exception.

EDIT,, used UInt64.Parse() not ulong.Parse() and the used string is "Hello" w/o quotation.

EDIT #2,,

so i did this based on knittl suggestion and used the Convert.ToUInt64 instead of the parse, but still getting same error

```
        ulong binary;
        string binThis;
        byte[] ByteThis;

        binThis = "Hello";

        ByteThis = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(binThis);

        binary = Convert.ToUInt64(ByteThis);

        Console.WriteLine(binary);
```

the CurrentCulture is set to en-US and i m also using en-US keyboard

EDIT #3 - Solved

thanks to knittl

the solution is as follow:

```
        string thestring = "example";
        string[] finale = new string[thestring.Length];

        foreach (var c in ByteThis)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ByteThis.Length; i++)
            {
                thestring = Convert.ToString(c, 2);
                thestring = "0" + thestring;
                if (thestring.Length == 9)
                    thestring.Remove(0, 1);
                finale[i] = thestring;
                Console.WriteLine(finale[i]);
            }
        }
```

the final for is to check on the solution.

this question aimed to get the binary representation of a given string.

Comment: I think you used `thiI` instead of `*string*` in your `Parse` method. What is the value of it exactly and what is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: i m using en-us for the w8.1 64, and in VS2012, as i said above, i used thiI, strValue, and hexThis. all what i got was the formartException.

Comment: No, I mean your `CurrentCulture` property. And the string value that you want to parse. Debug and tell us.

Comment: What is your input string?

Comment: @SonerGönül "en-US" is what i got after "          Console.WriteLine(thread.CurrentCulture.ToString());"

Comment: @knittl i m debugging the string "Hello" without quotes.

Comment: @user2332726 Are you sure? But how do you think you can parse `Hello` to `ulong` type? It doesn't even a valid integer. Are you sure you know what is a `string` and what is `ulong`?

Comment: @SonerGönül please read the edit.

Comment: @user2332726 `ulong` is an alias for `System.UInt64`. That's why `UInt64.Parse()` and `ulong.Parse()` are the same.

Comment: @SonerGönül i appreciate your clarification, my problem lies within the implementation of the method, i tried using multiple inputs but all i got was the same FormatException error, i tried using both of "UInt64 and ulong" parse methods, using both the System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber and the wrong int representation '16' of the hexadecimal system, while swapping hex, byte[], the input string strValue, and the representation of the string "Hello" with quotes.
on the other hand UInt64/ulong.Parse method returns the uint representation of the given string. yes i know string vs ulong.

Comment: Why is `16` a wrong int representation? That's just `10` when converted to base16, or `22` when converted to base10

Answer (score 1):

Not totally clear, what your method should do (i.e. what format the input string is. Is it a bas10 number, or already a hexadecimal number?)

If it's a hexadecimal number, use `ulong.Parse(inputStr, NumberStyles.HexNumber)`. If not, simply use `ulong.Parse(inputStr)`. Note that `NumberStyles.HexNumber` does **not** allow the `0x` prefix (`Convert.ToUInt64(inputStr)` does however).

Then, once you have your input string parsed to a number, simply use `Convert.ToString(number, 2)` to convert to base2. You will notice that there is no overload which takes an `ulong` and an `int`, but you can simply cast your number to a (signed) long, since the binary representation will be identical between the two (cf. two's complement). So, in effect `Convert.ToString((long)number, 2)`.

No need for complicated loops and conversions to byte arrays.

Comment: the input is the string "Hello" w/o quotation.
And your solution based on what you're saying should be something like this

byte[] hexThis = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hexValue.ToString());

ulong finale = ulong.Parse(hexThis);

is that correct?

Comment: What should the input `Hello` return? Why do you need the intermediate hex-conversion?

Comment: i used the hex, just in case i misunderstood the string format required as an input.
i updated the question, the function should take "string" and return its binary representation as a stream or string of 0,1.

Comment: So you need to get the bytes from the string (with the proper encoding), then loop over the bytes, convert each one to binary (`Convert.ToString(byte, 2)`) and use a `StringBuilder` to append everything together. No need to convert to a `long` inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

Bonus answer.

If you are not too concerned with performance, you can even use a LINQ one-liner:

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputStr).Aggregate(
  new StringBuilder(),
  (sb, ch) => sb.Append(Convert.ToString(ch, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')),
  sb => sb.ToString());
```